# Detecting consume failure with EasyNetQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

When I start consuming from a queue that is already locked by another exclusive consumer then no exception is thrown by the consume method, although I can see the error being logged. The `ExclusiveConsumer` keeps trying to start consuming every 10 seconds, which is great, but I would like to check (from code) when it hasn't started.

> Consume failed. queue='Queue1', consumer tag='cb439965-72d4-4d52-a248-91077b796703', message='The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=403, text="ACCESS_REFUSED - queue '1' in vhost '/' in exclusive use", classId=60, methodId=20, cause='

Is there any way I can detect the `Consumer` status without modifying the code?

Comment: Hmm, that might well be a bug. Can you raise it on the EasyNetQ list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/easynetq or raise an issue: https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/issues

Comment: @MikeHadlow I've looked at the code. Most of those operations are asynchronous, we don't have any way to handle the results. I have submitted a [pull](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/pull/429) request to add two events (consume success and failure). Let me know your preferred option.

Comment: FYI, I don't do much active development on EasyNetQ at the moment. Yuri Pliner and Michael Denny are more active core maintainers, so it's best to communicate via either GitHub or the Google Group rather than addressing me personally. But if you've submitted a pull request I expect someone would look at it soon.

Comment: @MikeHadlow No worries. I've joined the Google Group.